# Biztalk Send port calling .asmx service

Tags: biztalk

> Error details: System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException: The remote
>   server returned an unexpected response: (400) Bad Request. --->
>   System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400)
>   Bad Request.    at
>   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>   at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelAsyncRequest.CompleteGetResponse(IAsyncResult
>   result)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>
> Server stack trace:     at
>   System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
>   at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.SendAsyncResult.End(SendAsyncResult
>   result)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.EndCall(String action,
>   Object[] outs, IAsyncResult result)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.EndRequest(IAsyncResult
>   result)
>
> Exception rethrown at [0]:     at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage
>   reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)    at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&
>   msgData, Int32 type)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.IRequestChannel.EndRequest(IAsyncResult
>   result)    at
>   Microsoft.BizTalk.Adapter.Wcf.Runtime.WcfClient`2.RequestCallback(IAsyncResult
>   result)   MessageId:  {656781BB-FFA0-466B-A001-83ADCD4EEB78}

used BasicHTTPbindings...no login credentials. Works while testing with other WCF testing tools.

Comment: `.asmx` is for `ASP.Net` web services, and `.svc` is for `WCF` web services. The two are different. I'm not surprised that you cannot invoke an .asmx web method using a WCF client. Are you sure that this is supposed to work?

Comment: You can invoke .asmx serivces from a WCF client. It should use BasicHTTP bindings. I am doing this today and have no issues. What I am missing here is what the remote error is here. I suspect that it is a bad SOAP request. If you debug the remote asmx service and put a break point on the first line of your web method, is the call making it into the break point? If not, then the call isn't formatted properly and IIS is catching it and returning bad request because the signature of your call isn't matching the signature of the Web Method. An error in the method should return a 50x.

Comment: Use **HTTP Fiddler** and see what happens when you call the web service using WCF testing tools, where it works and compare the same when calling from Biztalk. It should give you a clue.

Answer (score 0):

You should set up this web-server to return the error text to the caller. By default (for security reasons) it does not return it. Also you could attach the debugger to the web-service and localize the problem with request.